# Do I need to await for each nested array of promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

In the below code I have used `await Promise.all` for every async function which then finally returns a value. So I'd like to ask: Is it necessary to use `await Promise.all` for every async function or will a single await (placed at the last) `await Promise.all` do the job?

```
async sendEmailNotifications() {
  const users = await User.find({  })
  const promises = users.map(async(user) => {
    const _promises = user.appId.map(async(app) => {
      const myApp = await App.findOne({ _id: app })
      if (myApp) {
        const sendNotification = await emailService.analyticsNotification(emailObj)
      }
    })
    await Promise.all(_promises)
  })
  await Promise.all(promises)
  return 'done'
}
```

Comment: you are not returning anything in your .map function.

Comment: @AshishKumar I don't want to return anything from the `.map`. I just want to wait till my map function is being done.

Comment: @AshishKumar The `.map` is useful here because he's using async functions, which return Promises automatically, and he wants to wait for all Promises to complete.

Comment: If all your interested in is if all promises have complete, the answer is no, you could just use one `Promise.all`,  looking at you code I cannot see anything in the inner loop that's going to return anything to the outer, so awaiting the inner `Promise.all` wouldn't gain anything.  But saying this, I think using 2 might be better anyway depending on how much is in each `map`, because too much in one single `Promise.all` may lead to thrashing, this is were a concurrency map would be better.  Your 2 promise.all may still have thrashing issues here, maybe the outer might be better as a `for of`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both `Promise.all`s are necessary for your current implementation. An async function returns a Promise. If there are no `await`s inside that function, and that function doesn't explicitly return a Promise, the Promise will resolve immediately. So, without

```
await Promise.all(_promises)
```

or

```
return Promise.all(_promises)
```

, your `const promises = users.map` array will result in an array of promises which all resolve immediately. You need the inner `Promise.all` in order for the overall `sendEmailNotifications` function's Promise to resolve only once all `.findOne`s and `analyticsNotification`s are complete.

Keep in mind that in your current code, all the requests are being sent out at once; no iteration depends on the last iteration's Promise being completed first, if that's what you're worried about. The only code-blocking behavior is in

```
  const myApp = await App.findOne({ _id: app })
  if (myApp) {
    const sendNotification = await emailService.analyticsNotification(emailObj)
  }
```

where the `.findOne` must resolve before `analyticsNotification` runs, but that logic looks to be required, and there's no way around it.

I suppose it would be *technically possible* to change your code into a single huge array of Promises that you call `Promise.all` on *once*, by having every `user.appId` item get transformed into a Promise and pushed to an external array, but that's less functional, results in uglier code, and doesn't have any benefit, IMO.

Comment: Thank you very much... *where the .findOne must resolve before analyticsNotification runs* why? I did check this and most of the time it wait until my `analyticsNotification` function returns the value. What do you think to be wrong here? Do you think it will jump outside the `if` condition and failure can be possible?

Comment: I just assumed that because your current logic depends on it. You *need* to know the truthyness of `myApp` in order to know if you need to run `analyticsNotification`. That's not a problem, there's nothing wrong with it, it's just the logic required (right?)

Comment: This is also what I am curious to know. Does await inside `if` condition wait for the underneath code. Or just executes it? Well I tested this as well and it works but when I should not instinctive. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, `await` will prevent code below in the same function from running.

Comment: Just a simple question certainPerformance. Is the above code using nested `await` is good approach or has any limiations? What If I use `Promise.all()` Instead?. Does Promise.all is faster then async await? Kindly reply.

Comment: `await` (waits for a single Promise to resolve) is a replacement for `Promise.prototype.then` - `Promise.all` is something different altogether (which waits for each Promise in an array to resolve). Performance-wise, there's absolutely nothing wrong with any of the code in the question - there's nothing significant I would change about it.

Comment: Actually I had have debate on this with my boss. And he said *"The nested async await is much slower then `Promise.all` and created multiple threads."* And now told me to change the code. But If I will have some substantial proof   then I can fight with him for this. So there is no performance issue, both will perform same?

Comment: I'm not very clear on the difference between the two codes you're thinking about - the codes in the question and in the answer uses both `Promise.all` and `await`, and since they do fundamentally different things, I'm not sure how one would replace one with the other. Can you post an example of the two codes you're thinking about on JSFiddle or something?